# How to import data from sqlserver into hdfs/hive/hbase

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, sqoop, hadoop2

I've import data of MYSQL into hive & hbase. Now I want to import data from sql server.

For this, I used this command.

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://<server_name>\<instance_name>;databaseName=<db_name>;user=<user_name>;password=<password>" --table test_vijay --hbase-table emp1 --column-family edetail --hbase-row-key id
```

But it gives me exception.

**14/12/24 11:51:53 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.micro
soft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host ARLMSSQLDEV02
, named instance dart_dev has failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: R
eceive timed out". Verify the server and instance names, check that no firewall
is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434, and for SQL Server 2005 or later verify th
at the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.**

How to solve this? Any Suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a permission issue , I would suggest to check one if in the DB side  user= has the access, second thing is to check if the Db instance is reachable from your hadoop/hbase machine.

Answer (score 0):

CAn you try once using IP address instead of Hostname.I think its not able to resolve the hostname.Also check if the required ports are opened.